# Can't install anything on pip

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, matplotlib

Everytime I try to install anything on pip it ends with following error message.

```
The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.

This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.
```

Specifically I tried matplotlib, seaworth and pandas. While the latter worked in the Windows Console, but doesn't work in the pycharm package manager.

Answer (score 14):

For those who encounter this and need to use Python 3.8+, make sure to update you setuptools to version 42.0.0 (or later).

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem with python 3.8.0

I uninstalled python 3.8 and installed 3.7.5 and it seems to have been fixed.